# Skip boot menu at Ubuntu startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have recently installed Ubuntu on an old Windows 10 laptop and I've then use gparted to remove the Windows partition and managed to give myself rights to the storage drive.

Windows is gone (I think) but I still get asked to choose between Windows and Ubuntu at start up.

Is there a way for me to skip over the boot menu at startup and go direct to desktop in order to speed up my startup experience?

Comment: Try first (in Ubuntu) to run the following command in a terminal window: **`sudo update-grub`** and check what happens when you reboot. Let us know the result (maybe it is enough, maybe you need something more advanced).

Comment: do you have efi boot

Comment: No i've tried the efi method found in another post and the system said something to the effect of "no efi on this system".

Comment: I've updated the grub as requested this was the output:  
                      

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'

Generating grub configuration file ...

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-46-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic

Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf

Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin

done

Thing is that it's still loading the boot order at startup just removed windows. How can I skip this ?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you still see Windows in a boot menu? If I understand your result (from your comment), there is nothing about Windows in the grub menu. So there must be another menu, where you see Windows. I think this menu is activated before the boot process reaches `grub` (which is the bootloader of Ubuntu). Maybe you can check the UEFI/BIOS system menus and see if you can find where to modify it -- This belongs to the computer (and can differ a lot between computer brands and models), so my experience of booting Ubuntu does not help much.

Comment: Please tell us about the computer: **Brand name and model**. Then we can hope that someone who owns such a computer will read this and tell you how to solve your problem.

Comment: @sudodus please see my answer.

Comment: @heynnema, Yes, that should work to get rid of the grub menu. I interpreted the OP's comment that there is another menu. You may be right, that there is still a grub menu after `update-grub`, even when no other operating system is found. And then your method should work. -- Let us wait and see the response from the OP, Andrea David Edelman.

Comment: Sudodus: no windows is gone. Computer brand name and model: MSI gaming laptop model MS-16GF.  Efi: there isn't one according to the system and the whole drive is being used. The problem was a left over windows entry in the grub menu, now gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the GRUB menu not appear at all, unless you hold down the SHIFT or ESC keys, do this...

In the `terminal`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

locate:

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`

change it to:

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`

then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @user68186 from the grub manual... "If 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE' is set to 'countdown' or 'hidden', the timeout is instead counted before the menu is displayed." Source: `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`

Comment: It worked ! thanks a lot, my pc is now 100% Ubuntu and 0% windows 7 :) Thanks for your help everyone.