# Remove All Windows, and reallocate space to Ubuntu Install

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I bought a ibm thinkpad t430used and it came with Windows 10.

Since my SSD is only 120GB I wanted to remove windows, and reallocate that current 72GB that Windows 10 is using to my ubuntu install.

How can I do that?

My partitions currently look like:
[image: img]

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: An advice: go to a fresh install of Ubuntu erasing everything. Of course after having made a backup of your files & documents. BUT you can if you want simply delete the Win10 partition and resize the Linux ones from a live usb stick. What do you prefer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Backup Backup Backup

Backup all your data, documents, songs, pictures, videos, etc. etc. What you are trying to do is dangerous. Make two backups. Test them to make sure you can restore from them.

Don't backup in the internal hard drive. Backup in an external storage media.

## Boot from Live USB/DVD

As we are going to change the Ubuntu system partition, we cannot use the Ubuntu that is already installed. We need a Live USB/DVD. Either a Live USB or a DVD will work. I will just call it a Live USB here.

Boot from a Live USB version of Ubuntu. Use the Try Ubuntu without installing option.

1. Use the application called Gparted in the Live USB.
2. Make sure the correct hard drive is selected.
3. Delete the partition `/dev/sda2` above. Note that it may be called
   something else when you use the Live USB.
4. **Apply the Changes (Nothing happens until you Apply)**
5. Now Windows is gone for ever, so is all the documents, music etc.
   you saved in Windows.
6. Highlight the **Extended Partition 4** in the above picture. This
   may be called `/dev/sda4`. Note, inside this extended partition, there are two logical partitions. `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`. Our final goal is to increase the size of `/dev/sda5`. But to that we need to make room for it in `/dev/sda4.`
7. Expand the `/dev/sda4` to the left to take up all the empty space
   created by deleting `/dev/sda2`.
8. **Apply the Changes.**
9. Highlight `/dev/sda5`.
10. Expand the `/dev/sda5` to the left to take up all the empty space
    created inside `/dev/sda4`.
11. **Apply the Changes.**

You are done. Exit Gparted. Shutdown the Live USB. Unplug the USB. Turn the PC back on. If all goes well, you should boot Ubuntu.

You may still see the Grub menu that gives you the option to boot Windows, but that option will not work anymore.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Ubuntu and enter:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should get rid of the Windows option.

You may still see the Grub menu at the boot time. You can hide the Grub menu by a small edit to Grub.

In the same terminal use the following commands:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then save the file and exit gparted.

Finally in the same terminal: enter

```
sudo update-grub
```

again to make the edit you just made take effect.

This last part is from [Skip boot menu at Ubuntu startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125309/skip-boot-menu-at-ubuntu-startup)

Hope this helps